# Seam entity does not persist database

Tags: database, hibernate, entity, seam, persist

i use seam framework to develop a web site. I want to share one problem when developing time. I have a one seam test method as succeding ;

```
    @Test
    public void saveTwoCategoryToRoot() throws Exception {
    new FacesRequest() {

        Category enduringRoot = new Category(
                ItemTreeVocabulary.ROOTNODE_NAME);

        protected void beforeRequest() {
            // clear database..
            clearDb();

            enduringRoot.addChild(new Category(
                    ItemTreeVocabulary.COMPUTER));

            enduringRoot.addChild(new Category(
                    ItemTreeVocabulary.WHITE_GOODS));
        };

        protected void invokeApplication() throws Exception {

            // set the root to database..
            ((EntityManager) getValue("#{entityManager}")).persist(enduringRoot);

            // feth the root from database..
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List resultList = ((EntityManager) getValue("#{entityManager}")).createQuery(
                    "Select i From Item i").getResultList();

            Category root = (Category) resultList.get(0);

            // list shuld not to be empty..
            Assert.assertFalse(resultList.isEmpty());

            // checks the nodes in the first depth..
            **Assert.assertEquals(2, root.getChildren().size());**                   

            // assert rootNode name..
            Assert.assertEquals(((Category) resultList.get(0)).getName(),
                    ItemTreeVocabulary.ROOTNODE_NAME);
            // assert first node in first depth..
            Assert.assertEquals(((Category) resultList.get(0))
                    .getChildren().get(0).getName(),
                    ItemTreeVocabulary.COMPUTER);
            // assert second node in first depth..
            Assert.assertEquals(root
                    .getChildren().get(0).getName(),
                    ItemTreeVocabulary.WHITE_GOODS);
        };

    }.run();

}
```

Category class is;

```
@Entity
public class Category extends Item implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1154500438874768209L;

private List<Item> children;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String name) {
    this();
    setName(name);
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Item.class, mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Item> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void addChild(Item child) {
    if (children == null) {
        children = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    if (!children.contains(child)) {
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }
}

public void setChildren(List<Item> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Category other = (Category) obj;
    if (children == null) {
        if (other.children != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!children.equals(other.children))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Class of Item is ;

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name") })
public class Item implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8332532835833777840L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * Hold the item's parent.
 */
private Category parent;

/**
 * Hold the item's name.
 */
private String name;

private Long id;

@Transient
public List<Item> getChildren() {
    return null;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category.class)
public Category getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Category parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}


public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
 }
```

Following this method, when i was run to test, below exception is occured about bold line ;

```
 FAILED: saveOneCategoryToRoot
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<1>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:645)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:126)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:470)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:454)
at com.galaksiya.kobar.test.itemtree.CategoryTest$2.invokeApplication(CategoryTest.java:105)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request.invokeApplicationPhase(AbstractSeamTest.java:656)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request.emulateJsfLifecycle(AbstractSeamTest.java:605)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request.access$100(AbstractSeamTest.java:177)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request$2.doFilter(AbstractSeamTest.java:505)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request.run(AbstractSeamTest.java:499)
at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$FacesRequest.run(AbstractSeamTest.java:872)
at com.galaksiya.kobar.test.itemtree.CategoryTest.saveOneCategoryToRoot(CategoryTest.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:676)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1169)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1182)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:761)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:612)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:292)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
```

I dont understand why instance of 'whiteGoods' is not save database.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: WIthout seeing the source code of Category, it'll be hard to answer.

Comment: you're right. class of category and item are added .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that when you add an Item to a category's children, you only do it if the item is not already contained in the children. And the equels method of Category considers two categories equal if they have the same children, even if they don't have the same name. So your both categories are equal.